# Negative regular expression

Tags: regex

I'm a newbie with Regex.

I've create a regular expression :

```
.*\d{8,}.*\r?\n
```

Which will delete lines when they have 8 digits or more, but I want that to work opposite.

I want to delete those who have less than 8 digits.

I know its probably simple but I just can't find out how to do it.

Can you help me accoplish this?

Comment: In C# (you had the tag initially), you may achieve that without a regex.

Comment: Note that this regex match 8 or more **consecutive** numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use

```
^(?:\D*\d){0,7}\D*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jY5I9f/1)

**Details**:

- `^`  - start of a string
- `(?:\D*\d){0,7}` - 0 to 7 sequence of:

  - `\D*` - 0+ non-digits
  - `\d` - a digit
- `\D*` - 0+ non-digits
- `$` - end of string.

Since the `\D*` at the start is included into the *non-capturing* group (and is thus "repeated"), and the last one is not inside the group (not "repeated") the pattern is executed linearly, and does not cause much of a slowdown since the engine does not have to think about into which group to place the non-digit symbols.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
^(\D*\d\D*){0,7}$
```

It allows however many non-digit characters (`\D`) on the line, but makes sure there are not more than 7 digits.

Comment: This `^(\D*\d\D*){0,7}$` regex is prone to catastrophic backtracking, or can cause code execution slowdown.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for pointing that out! I learned something new today because of your comment and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*\d{8,}.*).*$
```